# Wubi installation on a Whole-Disk-encrypted system?

Tags: wubi, encryption

I have a laptop with Whole Disk Encryption. Can I still install using Wubi?

Comment: which encryption utility did you use to encrypt and which algorithm did you use?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to decrypt it on boot prior to loading Wubi then yes, otherwise, no.

E.g. Safeboot can do this but ymmv.  As always, backup your files regularly.